# FitNesse SliM - root page references to .class files MANY different projects

Tags: fitnesse

I am developing some fixtures in Java to use with fitnesse slim. I run into problems (**EXCEPTION**:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:) when I must update my root page with paths like this:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!path: C:\WORKSPACE\Projects\iperoom_67_workspace\acceptance_test_project\bin
!path: C:\WORKSPACE\Projects\iperoom_67_workspace\iperoom\BASE\common_util\target\classes
!path C:\WORKSPACE\Projects\iperoom_67_workspace\iperoom\BASE\dfc_util\target\classes
```

Where a class in i.e. ...BASE\dfc_util\target\classes; has the following imports:

import no.joint.iperoom.test.AbstractDfcTest;

code
.
.
.

Which gives the complete path in my local C drive workspace:

C:\WORKSPACE\Projects\iperoom_67_workspace\iperoom\BASE\dfc_util\target\classes\no\joint\iperoom\test

My question is could I say, on the root page:

classpath: C:\WORKSPACE\Projects\iperoom_67_workspace\iperoom\BASE*; as in take in all the .class files from here and up. Something more general?
and possibly import several pats to .class files on the fitnesse test page:

|import|
|dfc_util.target.classes.no.joint.iperoom.test.AbstractDfcTest|

Or is there any other and better way to solve this problem with a growing number of '!paths' in my root page due to calling one .class from another .class from antoher .class and so forth.

Or maybe my fixture code is not good enough:

public class SessionHelperTest /*extends AbstractDfcTest*/{

```
public boolean testNewSession() {

    System.out.println("Hello Joint");


    IDfSession session = SessionRegistry.getSuperUserSession("eRoomPCI_v_1_1");
try {
        String si = session.getSessionId();
        System.out.println("The sessionId is:\n" + si);
        return true;
    } catch (DfException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Cheers

Magnus

Answer (score 0):

I don't think path is going to work the way you want it to.  If you define it at too low a level, I'm pretty sure it won't find your classes.

The !path works fine when you do any of the following:

This will get all of the class files under build/classes if it is under the folder fitnesse starts in:

```
!path build/classes
```

This will handle multiple jar files:

```
!path lib/*.jar
```

Important to note is that you can leverage environment variables for this.  Assuming you have an environment variable called WORKSPACE defined that points to the base of your project, you can do this:

```
 !path ${WORKSPACE}/acceptance_test_project/bin
 !path ${WORKSPACE}/acceptance_test_project/common_util/target/classes
 !path ${WORKSPACE}/acceptance_test_project/dfc_util/target/classes
```

The reality is that if your files are scattered across multiple folders, you will have to use multiple entries.  If just to make sure you can control the order the path is processed.  If you only do this on your FrontPage, then everything below it will inherit the same path.  Then you only have to manage it in one location.  So while the list might be longer than you prefer, the maintenance is managed.